# Is it possible to use MacPorts to distribute custom software?

Tags: macports, software-distribution

We have some internal software tools that I need to distribute to our machines. Checking out the source repository is an option, but that would require putting the binaries into the repo, which I am not extatic about.

I thought it would be nice to use existing MacPorts infrastructure instead. We all have Macs and already use MacPorts, so it would make sense to install another port with our own tools. Is it possible to add another source of packages to the MacPorts system? Is it reasonably easy? Is it possible to add some authorization, so that other people can’t install our software off our server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should be able to add a source to your macports installation editing the file `sources.conf`, and adding the path of your custom repository. Take a look at [the official documentation](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/development.local-repositories.html).

Comment: I somehow managed to miss the section while skimming the docs, thank you. That appears to be exactly what I’m looking for.